# Scope of ng-click on a dynamically created button not working on Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to click on a button that was dynamically created when I click on the Google Map's marker by using InfoWindow, and there is nothing triggering it. [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) is the link that I followed. What am I missing here? Below are my code.

JS

```
$scope.openMap = function(test){
    console.log(test);
}

$scope.addMarker = function(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
    var contentString = 'Lat: '+location.lat+ ' lng: '+location.lng+
                        '<button ng-click="openMap("testing")">Map</button>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

The function addMarker will add a new marker location on the map. This function works and as noticed, the variable contentString was added to the attribute content in infowindow. The problem is $scope.openMap is not able to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to compile your html and add it.Add dependency for $compile and then change code to following.

```
var contentString = 'Lat: '+location.lat+ ' lng: '+location.lng+
                    '<button ng-click="openMap("testing")">Map</button>';

contentString = $compile(contentString)($scope);
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: angular js compiles all the code when first directive are created and assign behavior (clik, mouseup etc event)to it.So when your dynamically add any element then you need to compile it again and it will be having all scope's behavior.

Comment: Yeah, looked into it. Now it all makes sense on the scope's behavior. Thanks!